# serial usb communication in linux using minicom

Tags: linux, serial-port

I trying to use serial port in Linux. I am using minicom. When I connected my serial to USB device to  a port, minicom responds with

> "cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory".

But when dmesg it is showing that

> "converter now attached to ttyUSB0"

Then why it is not opening in minicom.

Comment: Did you use sudo when starting minicom or do you root permissions? Also what steps did you follow to setup minicom (did you use $minicom -s) before starting minicom

Comment: yes. I did. "sudo minicom -s" then "serial port" , tty8 -> ttyUSB0 then exit from minicom

Comment: can you find the ttyUSB0 listed under /dev on your PC

Answer (score 0):

It might due to not having access privilege.

Try this.

sudo chown  /dev/ttyUSB0